# Как изменить цвет у верхней и левой границы input

Tags: html, css

Html

```css
.count {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.1rem;
}
    
.count-input {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-color: #cfd3d5;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: #6e7c84;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-left-color: #cfd3d5 !important;
  border-top-color: #cfd3d5;
}
.count > input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.count > input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.count > input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.count button {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background-color: #e9ebec;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  line-height: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="count">
  <button id="down" on:click={decreaseBtn}>-</button>
  <input
    id="numericUpDown"
    class="count-input"
    type="number"
    value={qty}
  />
  <button id="up" on:click={increaseBtn}>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код по человечески, чтоб его можно было запустить на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте значение   ⠀**border-left-color** и
**border-top-color** ⠀у класса  **count-input**

```css
.count {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.1rem;
}
    
.count-input {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-color: #cfd3d5;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: #6e7c84;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-left-color: red; /********* Левая граница **********/
  border-top-color: blue; /******** Верхняя граница *********/
}
.count > input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.count > input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.count > input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.count button {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background-color: #e9ebec;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  line-height: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="count">
  <button id="down" on:click={decreaseBtn}>-</button>
  <input
    id="numericUpDown"
    class="count-input"
    type="number"
    value={qty}
  />
  <button id="up" on:click={increaseBtn}>+</button>
</div>
```